# Scanning for nearby bluetooth devices

Tags: android

If the phone has bluetooth toggled on, can an app read the list of the ids of nearby discoverable devices? If so, which function returns such a list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices)

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
```