# Scanning nearby Bluetooth devices via Android Wear?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

As mentioned by [rochdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745838/rochdev) for the question -

[scanning for nearby bluetooth devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479714/scanning-for-nearby-bluetooth-devices)

I was able to do so using my Android Phone. However, I tried to do the same thing on an Android wear (LG G Watch) and the same code does not seem to do the job.

Is there a way to find nearby bluetooth devices in an Android Wear app that uses the Bluetooth sensor on the Android watch rather than the Android phone?

My intention is to scan nearby bluetooth devices using the watch bluetooth sensor and then give the list of the name, addresses, signal strength of these devices to my Android phone.

Comment: Saying that "the same code does not seem to do the job" doesn't tell us much. What actually happened? Error messages? Logcat?

Comment: There is no error at all. It just does not display nearby devices.